# How to disconnect and reconnect PPPoE on a UBNT airMAX device?

Tags: networking, router, telnet, network-interface, pppoe

Using a Telnet or SSH connection to my Ubiquiti PowerBeam device, I'd like to disable and enable the PPPoE connection on demand, so I can save internet bandwidth when I am not using it. (Prevent background processes on my desktop PC and smartphone from wasting it.)

It has to be a programmatically approach, so I can control it using my scripts. Hence, using a terminal connection.

**How can I disable and then re-enable the PPPoE connection on a Ubnt airMAX device?**

Answer (score 0):

Looking at `pppinfo.cgi` and doing a `cat /usr/www/lib/settings.inc`, it seems that the router itself issues a `killall pppd` to restart the ppp daemon thus enabling it.

Also by issuing a *link down* command on interface *ppp0*, I was able to disconnect it from my ISP. You just need to send below commands using a Telnet client with whatever scripting language you are using.

**In order to modify the PPPoE service via command-line, I'd say:**

- To Disable: `ip link set ppp0 down`
- To Enable: `sudo killall pppd`

Tested on a *UBNT airMAX PowerBeam M5* via both SSH and Telnet.
I hope this helps future visitors.